# This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package

Tags: windows-installer, windows-11

When I try to install the .msi package in Windows 11 23H2, I got the following error:
[image]

(The translation to English is in the question header.) And it happens on **every** such package since system installation. The system image had been download from the official Microsoft site. Trivial methods such as [this](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/this-installation-package-could-not-be-opened) and [this](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-installer-package-fix-issues/) don't help. How to fix the problem?